# watir webdriver wait for font load

Tags: selenium, fonts, watir, watir-webdriver, asynchronous

I want to take a screenshot of a web page with watir. It should capture the final design of the page that a user would see.

I have the following problem:

The fonts are loaded somewhat after the pageload.
Thus, waiting for elements being `visible?` / `exists?` is not sufficient, as all html is already present on the page before the fonts are loaded. For those cases I only see the system standard fonts.

Does anyone know how to wait for fonts loading (except for using `sleep X`) with Watir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get font size using

```
b.div(:id => 'foo').style 'font-size'
```

Comment: But the font-size is the same for the initially loaded system-font. can I check the font-type/font name? I found nothing in the docs...

Comment: @finnvonfriesland You can get any CSS property. Try `font-style` or `font-family` instead of `font-size`.

Comment: thanks! that was the information I was looking for :)